# how to call view events in loop in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

i want to fire on_change events on dynamically created drop boxes.
    but have no idea how to do it in backbone js

```
here is my html code creating a div tag 

<div id="page">
    <input type="button"id="btn1"value="ok">
</div>
```

and its my backbone code where i am dynamically adding drop down in

```
var btn2id =""; 
    var app = {};app.v1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#page',    
    events: {
        'click #btn1' : 'f1',
    },
f1:function()
    {
        alert("Boom");
        btn2id="btn2";
for(var j=0;j<3;j++)    {
        $('#page').append('<select  id="selecty'+j+'"></select>');
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
         $('#selecty'+j+'').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
        }
vv = new app.v2();}}
    }
    });
app.v2 =Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#page',    
    events:{
     at this place i have no idea what to do
     //  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    //  'change '#selecty'+i+'' : 'f2',
     //    }
    },

f2:function()   {
        alert("Boom again");
    }
v = new app.v1();
    });
v = new app.v1();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, reusable components should have their on view. 
This practice lets you bind the recurring events easily, and in general matter cleans your code.

Note: in my code example I didn't use any template engine or practice, but I totally recommend you to do that.

So lets assume you have the main view with a button that creates new `select` elements:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el  :   "#main",
  events : {
        'click #add' : 'add',
  },
  add   :   function(){
    var select = new SelectView();
    this.$el.append(select.render().el);
  }
});
```

As you can see, anytime `#add` is clicked, it creates a new `SelectView` which represents the `select` element.

And the select element itself:

```
var SelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
    'change select' : 'doSomething'
  },
  doSomething:  function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).css('color','red');
  },
    render: function(){
    this.$el.html("<select />");
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        this.$el.find('select').append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>")
    }
    return this;
  }
});
```

In my dummy example I just change the color of the element when it is changed. You can do whatever.
So, it is now super easy to bind events to the select views.

In general, I would recommend you that when you are working with reusable components, you should always think of a practice which makes things make sense.
This is one of many ways to do that, but it is pretty simple to understand and implement.

You are welcome to see the "live" example: http://jsfiddle.net/akovjmpz/2/

Comment: And if all those extra views are too heavy, just add a `class` to the `<select>`s and use that `class` as the selector in `events`.